# Ошибка при установке приложения angular-phonecat

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, angularjs

```
ubuntu 14.04
nodejs 5.7.1
npm 3.6.0
```

Хочу установить angular-phonecat приложение из оффициального сайта angular:

```
npm install
```

и

```
npm start
```

Выдает такие ошибки, но при этом приложение работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Comment: Вам же белым по фиолетовому пишут "_g++ не найден_". Установите `g++`.

Comment: А ещё лучше пакет "build-essential".